# Collections are not allowed in sub classes in Table per subclass using a discriminator

Tags: hibernate

I am using Inheritance strategy : Table Per subclass strategy using discriminator.

**My POJO Class as below**

```
public abstract Class A{
...
}

public Class B extends A{
private List <D> collection
......
}

public Class C extends A{
..........
}

public class D{
.........
}
```

**Hibernate Mapping as below**

```
 <hibernate-mapping>

 <class name="A" entity-name="A"
    abstract="true"  discriminator-value="ABS_A"
    table="A">
     <id name="id" type="java.lang.String">
        <column not-null="true" unique="false" name="`ID`" />
      </id>
      <discriminator type="string">
        <column name="`ABS_A_DISCRIMINATOR`" index="A_discriminator"
            length="255" not-null="true" />
       </discriminator>
             ........................
      </class>

       <subclass extends="A" entity-name="B"
          name="B"
          discriminator-value="B">

        <join table="B" fetch="select">
         <key><column name="ID" /></key>
          <list name="collection" table="B_D" cascade="all" lazy="true">
        <key column="ID" />
        <list-index column="idx" />
           <many-to-many entity-name="D" unique="false">
             </many-to-many>
                </list>
           ....................
         </join>
       </subclass>

       <subclass extends="A" entity-name="C"
          name="C"
          discriminator-value="C">

        <join table="C" fetch="select">
         <key><column name="ID" /></key>
         ................
         </join>
       </subclass>

    <class name="D" entity-name="D" table="D">
    .....................
     </class>
<hibernate-mapping>
```

I am getting the below exception
  The content of element type "join" must match "(subselect?,comment?,key,(property|many-to-one|component|dynamic-component|any)*,sql-insert?,sql-update?,sql-delete?)".

If join tag does not allows list/set/idbag/bag, Is there any other way to achieve this .. I came to this problem because of unnecessary joins happening when i use table per subclass without discriminator strategy.

Note: Strictly I want normalized db model.

Thanks in Advance!...

Answer (score 0):

We can add list under the subclass tag like as below

```
<subclass extends="A" entity-name="B"
          name="B"
          discriminator-value="B">

  <list name="collection" table="B_D" cascade="all" lazy="true">
        <key column="ID" />
        <list-index column="idx" />
         many-to-many entity-name="D" unique="false">
           </many-to-many>
  </list>

 ...............
</subclass>
```

join tag does allows list inside.